# Yii rules for checkboxes

Tags: php, yii

I have many checkbox **fields** in my model. I need a validation rule that can verify the number of checked checkboxes. Note that **each** checkbox has a corresponding field.

Comment: Nothing. I'm still searching for a solution.

Comment: There is the possibility to write a function to be called by the validation rule, but, if possible, i want to use a validation rule instead.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you need, but you should create ur own validator. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#rules-detail or using one that comes with Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator

Comment: Thanks, Jorge. I had already looked at the documentation. The available Yii validators don't seem to do what I want. But I had the expectation that someone solved the same problem without writing a function for it.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/#hh0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own validation rule. There's no rule for it.